# Cannot run simple android application in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have successfully installed the Eclipse, and Android SDK to my Mac. However when I run the program using the code below, it will run but does not give the expected output.

I have followed the instructions from [this site](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) and the output doesn't match that described.

I get output in android UI like: display date and time and charging(50%) like that

Below is my Console output

```
[2011-05-04 10:24:59 - Emulator]
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] ------------------------------
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] Android Launch!
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] Performing com.example.HelloRelativeLayout.HelloRelativeLayout activity launch
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-05-04 10:25:05 - HelloRelativeLayout] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-05-04 10:25:07 - HelloRelativeLayout] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-04 10:25:07 - HelloRelativeLayout] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-05-04 10:26:15 - HelloRelativeLayout] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-04 10:26:15 - HelloRelativeLayout] Uploading HelloRelativeLayout.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-04 10:26:16 - HelloRelativeLayout] Installing HelloRelativeLayout.apk...
[2011-05-04 10:27:36 - HelloRelativeLayout] Success!
[2011-05-04 10:27:36 - HelloRelativeLayout] Starting activity com.example.HelloRelativeLayout.HelloRelativeLayout on device emulator-5554
[2011-05-04 10:27:39 - HelloRelativeLayout] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.HelloRelativeLayout/.HelloRelativeLayout }
```

Below is the stack trace from LogCat

```
05-04 10:35:47.342: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.355: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ef (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.362: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ee (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.362: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ed (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.377: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ec (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.384: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800eb (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.392: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ea (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.403: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.403: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.533: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 9% free 2705K/2947K, paused 3ms+9ms
05-04 10:35:47.533: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.542: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e2 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.555: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e1 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.563: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.563: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800df (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.577: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800de (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.583: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800dd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.693: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 7% free 2749K/2947K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:47.708: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800dc (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.712: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.712: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.721: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.732: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d6 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.732: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d5 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.742: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d4 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.753: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d3 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.753: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d2 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.872: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 8% free 2791K/3011K, paused 3ms+10ms
05-04 10:35:47.883: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800cd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.892: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800cc (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.892: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800cb (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.913: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.929: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.932: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080179 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:47.942: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080178 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.052: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 8% free 2838K/3075K, paused 9ms+8ms
05-04 10:35:48.062: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080177 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.062: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080176 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.082: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080175 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.082: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080174 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.092: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080173 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.103: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080172 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.103: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080171 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.112: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080170 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.125: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016f (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.242: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 7% free 2880K/3075K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:48.257: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.263: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.263: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.272: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.283: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.293: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080169 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.302: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080168 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.311: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080167 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.432: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 7% free 2921K/3139K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:48.432: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080166 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.441: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080165 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.454: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080164 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.462: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080163 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.462: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080162 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.482: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080120 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_transparent_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.482: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.497: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_pressed_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.503: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.612: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 6% free 2965K/3139K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:48.633: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.633: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.643: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080119 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.652: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080118 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_disable_focused.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.652: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080117 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_disable.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.663: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080116 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.683: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080115 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.692: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080114 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.702: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080113 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_disabled_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.812: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 7% free 3005K/3203K, paused 4ms+2ms
05-04 10:35:48.832: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080112 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_disabled_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.832: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080111 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_disabled_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.848: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080110 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.851: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010f (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.851: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.872: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.872: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:48.882: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.003: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 5% free 3047K/3203K, paused 4ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:49.013: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108010a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.021: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080109 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_disable_focused.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.021: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080108 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_disable.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.042: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080107 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.042: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080104 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.052: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080103 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.065: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080102 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.072: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080101 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.182: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 6% free 3091K/3267K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:49.182: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080100 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.192: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ff (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.203: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801de (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_pressed_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.213: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801dd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.222: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801dc (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_normal_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.222: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801db (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_normal_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.243: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.243: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.352: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 6% free 3137K/3331K, paused 4ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:49.362: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_disabled_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.374: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d6 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_disabled_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.383: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d5 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.396: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d4 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.401: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d3 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.401: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d2 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_pressed_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.422: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d1 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.422: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_normal_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.542: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 5% free 3181K/3331K, paused 3ms+2ms
05-04 10:35:49.552: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801cf (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_normal_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.562: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801cd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.573: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801cc (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.573: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801cb (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_disabled_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.582: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ca (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_disabled_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.595: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.602: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.602: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.732: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 6% free 3224K/3395K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:49.732: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10802b2 (res/drawable-mdpi/ic_emergency.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.742: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080013 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_textfield.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.753: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080222 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.753: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080014 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.763: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080221 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.774: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080012 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.774: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080228 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_vertical_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.852: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080246 (res/drawable/edit_text_holo_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:49.963: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 4% free 3266K/3395K, paused 9ms+8ms
05-04 10:35:50.037: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080245 (res/drawable/edit_text_holo_dark.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.062: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080016 (res/drawable/edit_text.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.187: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 3% free 3319K/3395K, paused 3ms+8ms
05-04 10:35:50.212: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108025d (res/drawable/expander_group.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.231: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108025e (res/drawable/expander_group_holo_dark.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.252: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108025f (res/drawable/expander_group_holo_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.303: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080062 (res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.453: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 2% free 3395K/3459K, paused 9ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:50.493: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080371 (res/drawable/list_selector_background_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.503: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080372 (res/drawable-mdpi/list_selector_background_longpress.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.503: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080373 (res/drawable-mdpi/list_selector_background_longpress_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.503: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080374 (res/drawable-mdpi/list_selector_background_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.503: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080375 (res/drawable-mdpi/list_selector_background_pressed_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.514: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080376 (res/drawable-mdpi/list_selector_background_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.632: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 3% free 3443K/3523K, paused 4ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:50.665: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080380 (res/drawable/list_selector_holo_dark.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.693: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080381 (res/drawable/list_selector_holo_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.693: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108038c (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.707: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108038d (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.713: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080392 (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_submenu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.752: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080390 (res/drawable/menu_selector.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.862: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 3% free 3504K/3587K, paused 4ms+3ms
05-04 10:35:50.883: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803d3 (res/drawable-mdpi/panel_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.893: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e0 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.901: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e1 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.912: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e2 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.922: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e3 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.922: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e4 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.932: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e5 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:50.943: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e6 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_full_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.063: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 3% free 3550K/3651K, paused 3ms+9ms
05-04 10:35:51.083: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803e7 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.083: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803ee (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.102: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803ef (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.102: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803ea (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_inline_error_above_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.122: WARN/Zygote(31): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803eb (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_inline_error_above_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-04 10:35:51.231: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 2% fr
```

Comment: I don't see any error in the LOGCAT. Were you expecting any output in the logs or are you seeing problems with your UI?

Comment: "It will run but not gives an exact output" what you mean by this is unclear to me

Comment: what output it gives? The log does not contain much to understand your problem

Comment: It looks like you're running one of the apidemos ... they don't compile well by themselves. Try running something in its own package.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the code you're referencing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but you *have* unlocked the emulator right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based around the description you've given, I'd say you're getting the locked screen the emulator displays when it first starts up: [image: Emulator]

If so, you need to click on the padlock and drag it to the right, to unlock the emulator...  Then you should start seeing output.

[image]

If not, goto the apps element and check to see if hello world has been installed correctly.

Comment: I think this is the answer which chetan is looking for.

Comment: great buddy you exact understand what i what to say.Its work fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you must wait a long time for the emulator. On a slower machine, sometimes it can take 10 minutes. Maybe this helps...